# full size responsive background images without strech

Tags: css

Im using Full page scroll for a site https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

Im trying to give each "page" a background image that is resizable. i'm using cover image css rule this works for the first page but not any of the others. Am i doing something wrong is it is not possible this way?

Any help is appreciated thanks :)

HTML

```
<section class="page1 ops-section" data-index="1"> </section>
<section class="page2 ops-section" data-index="2"> </section>
<section class="page3 ops-section" data-index="3"> </section>
<section class="page4 ops-section" data-index="4"> </section>
<section class="page5 ops-section" data-index="5"> </section>
<section class="page6 ops-section" data-index="6"> </section>
```

CSS

```
  .main section.page1 {
  background: url(bg1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .main section.page2 {
  background: url(bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .main section.page3 {
  background: url(bg3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .main section.page4 {
  background: url(bg4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .main section.page5 {
  background: url(bg5.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
  .main section.page6 {
  background: url(bg6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a demo page?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `background-image` to the containing element instead of the pages that the plugin changes?  The plugin might be doing something that is breaking it.  Since the `page` class is the parent container that the plugin works with, I wouldn't add anything to it if possible.

Comment: You need to define the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the page to have a resizable background image then the CSS you have used seems to be appropriate.

However, you have applied this class to a section which has no fixed hieght and does not have display block.

HTML:

```
<section class="page1 ops-section" data-index="1"> </section>
```

CSS:

```
.main section.page2 {
  background: url(bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Just look at the difference between the section titled 'page1' and 'page2' at the following fiddle. Page2 section has display block and a fixed height and the background image is visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nst62/

A more advisable way to achieve the resizable background image cover style would be to apply it to the HTML tag instead (See the fiddle below).

http://jsfiddle.net/pTQQ4/

This way you don't have to ensure that the section has to 'fill' the entire height of the browser window.

Comment: This works with the hack around !important added the css rules thanks :)